# Flink Streaming Job execution graph analyse

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have some question in terms of performance with Flink,

Can someone tell me what is wrong if my program has an execution plan same as the picture below?

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cywCh.png)

Comment: Why are you concerned?

Comment: Context: I'm trying to enhance the performance of the current CEP, the goal is to detect patterns from N input streams that can have different types, patterns can depend on m<N input streams. Solution: An idea is to partition the data with respect to the requirements of each given pattern.
● We transform each input dataStream into a keystream with an ID as a key.
● Analyse the given patterns to identify input data requirements.
● Union all required input data and group them with the same key in order to have a
shared state.  I want to understand what are the drawbacks of this Solution. Thy

Answer (score 0):

From your description I cannot immediately see, why you need more than one `hash` per source. Any kind of network shuffle limits throughput, so avoiding all unnecessary shuffles seems like the best solution in your case.

The final picture should look like

```
Source 1 --\
            \
Source 2 ----\
              +---> Map ---> Sink
...          /
            /
Source N --/
```

Such that each input record is only rekeyed once.

Aside from these general consideration, I'd need much more details and CEP pseudocode to give more specific recommendations.